# how to delete all files in directory except one folder and one file?

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins

I have application which has one folder called vendor and one file called .env. When ever i automatically publish my source code files to folder, all old files should get deleted except these two.

How can i do this in linux by using shell?

PS : I am trying to implement rollback mechanism in Jenkins. I will copy artifacts from old build and transfer them to server using ssh. But this will be a copy operation. So I want to delete previous files before starting copy using SSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find ! \( -name 'name1' -o -name  'name2' \) -exec rm -r {} +
```

Comment: @123 Yes, but just as long as the folder is empty

Answer (score 1):

try with this command 
`rm !(<filename>)`

Comment: `shopt -s extglob` might be needed.